# How to use Stored String value in another block of code

Tags: java

I am fetching some String of words from array list and I am removing some words in the string so now I have Printed that word and I am initializing to Client Name so now I want to insert that stored thing in the database so now it is not recognized Client name since it is in different block so how to fetch that data

```
        String s;

        String keyword = arra.get(6);

        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if (s.contains(keyword)) {
                s = s.replaceAll(keyword, " ");
                System.out.println(s);

                String Client_Name = s;

            }

        }

        try {
            Connection conn = PDFTOEXCEL.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into client_info values(?)");

            stmt.setString(1, Client_Name);

            int k = stmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("rows affected : " + k);
```

Comment: Declare it in the same scope that you wish to use it

Comment: Use a method, pass `Client_Name` as a parameter to it

Comment: I am not getting  MadProgrammer

Comment: i want to use them in different block only

Comment: in same project, package?? or in just same class??

Comment: in the same class

Answer (score 0):

You look very new to Java programming. As mentioned in the comments, try to go through some Java tutorials or read some good Java books to get better understanding and hands-on. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/ details how scopes work.

Now for your problem, the issue is you have declared client_name inside if block; so the scope of this variable ends as soon as program comes out of if-block and it won't be reachable after it. Try declaring Client_Name (use proper naming conventions also) outside while and if block (similar to String s declaration; also you don't seem to need both s and Client_Name as per your logic) and you should be good to go.

Sample code -

```
        String clientName;

        String keyword = arra.get(6);

        while ((clientName = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if (clientName.contains(keyword)) {
                clientName = clientName.replaceAll(keyword, " ");
                System.out.println(clientName);    
            }

        }

        try {
            Connection conn = PDFTOEXCEL.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into client_info values(?)");

            stmt.setString(1, clientName);

            int k = stmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("rows affected : " + k);
```

Comment: @Deo - This is a sample code which I have not tried. You need to make sure that at least one line contains the keyword. If none of the line contains it, you need to handle that condition as well.